# Form only displays when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to create a mock ice-cream shop website in order to improve my JavaScript. The trouble with this page is that each radio button, upon being checked, is meant to display one of two forms. Unfortunately, it does not work - I have to refresh the page after checking the checkbox for the form to display. Why is this? How do I fix it?

Lines 21-26 were originally in init. I moved them in case having them in their own function would help somehow, but it did nothing, as expected. I really don't know why this isn't working.

```js
function hideDeliveryAndPickup() {
  // var pickupDiv = document.getElementById("pickupDiv");
  // var deliveryDiv = document.getElementById("deliveryDiv");
  // pickupDiv.style.display = "none";
  // deliveryDiv.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.display = "none";
}

function showPickup() {
  document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.display = "none";
}

function showDelivery() {
  document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.display = "none";
}

function showDeliveryOrPickup() {
  if (document.getElementById("pickup").checked == true) {;
    showPickup();
  }
  if (document.getElementById("delivery").checked == true) {
    showDelivery();
  }
}

function validate() {

}

function init() {
  hideDeliveryAndPickup();
  showDeliveryOrPickup();
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Order Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Order page for Sweet Life.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="study">
  <meta name="author" content="Anon">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/script3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="orderhtml">
    <!--Header-->
    <header>
      <h1 class="header" id="headerTop">Sweet Life</h1>
      <h2 class="header" id="headerBottom">Discover a world of ice cream...</h2>
    </header>
    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="topnav">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="order.html">Order online</a>
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tagline">
      <h2>Order</h2>
    </div>
    <!--Form-->
    <form>
      <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
      <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
      <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="chooseDiv" value="Delivery"><br>
      <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
      <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="chooseDiv" value="Pickup"><br>
    </form>
    <div id="pickupDiv">
      <br/>
      <p>A's text</p>
      <form id="orderPickupForm">
        <label for="fName">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" value=""><br>
        <label for="lName">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" value="">
        <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value=""><br>
        <select name="selectIceCream" id="selectIceCream">
          <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
          <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
          <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        </select><br>
        <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
        <select name="selectSize" id="selectSize">
          <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
          <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
          <option value="1L">1L</option>
          <option value="2L">2L</option>
        </select><br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="deliveryDiv">
      <br/>
      <p>B's text</p>
      <form id="orderDeliveryForm">
        <label for="firstN">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="firstN" name="firstN" value=""><br>
        <label for="lastN">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lastN" name="lastN" value="">
        <label for="emailA">Email address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="emailA" name="emailA" value=""><br>
        <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
        <select name="selectIceCream">
          <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
          <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
          <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        </select><br>
        <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
        <select name="selectSize">
          <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
          <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
          <option value="1L">1L</option>
          <option value="2L">2L</option>
        </select><br>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are missing event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing event handlers. You need to detect the click and run the script.

Here is an improved version using delegation to detect any click in the radio container. It is a COMPLETE replacement for ALL the code you posted here.

Note I added `hidden` to the two divs

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page has loaded
  container = document.getElementById("orderhtml");
  const pickupDiv = document.getElementById("pickupDiv");
  const deliveryDiv = document.getElementById("deliveryDiv");
  container.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const tgt = event.target;
    if (!tgt.matches("[name=chooseDiv]")) return; // not a radio
    const delivery = tgt.id === "delivery";
    deliveryDiv.hidden = !delivery;
    pickupDiv.hidden = delivery
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="orderhtml">
  <!--Header-->
  <header>
    <h1 class="header" id="headerTop">Sweet Life</h1>
    <h2 class="header" id="headerBottom">Discover a world of ice cream...</h2>
  </header>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <div id="topnav">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="order.html">Order online</a>
      <a href="register.html">Register</a>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="tagline">
    <h2>Order</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Form-->
  <form>
    <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
    <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
    <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="chooseDiv" value="Delivery"><br>
    <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
    <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="chooseDiv" value="Pickup"><br>
  </form>

  <div id="pickupDiv" hidden>
    <br/>
    <p>A's text</p>
    <form id="orderPickupForm">
      <label for="fName">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" value=""><br>
      <label for="lName">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" value="">
      <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
      <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value=""><br>
      <select name="selectIceCream" id="selectIceCream">
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
      </select><br>
      <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
      <select name="selectSize" id="selectSize">
        <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
        <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
        <option value="1L">1L</option>
        <option value="2L">2L</option>
      </select><br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="deliveryDiv" hidden>
    <br/>
    <p>B's text</p>
    <form id="orderDeliveryForm">
      <label for="firstN">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="firstN" name="firstN" value=""><br>
      <label for="lastN">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lastN" name="lastN" value="">
      <label for="emailA">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="emailA" name="emailA" value=""><br>
      <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
      <select name="selectIceCream">
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
      </select><br>
      <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
      <select name="selectSize">
        <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
        <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
        <option value="1L">1L</option>
        <option value="2L">2L</option>
      </select><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can improve the script by using data-attributes on the radio

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page has loaded
  const container = document.getElementById("orderhtml");
  const divs = container.querySelectorAll("div[hidden]");
  container.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const tgt = event.target;
    if (!tgt.matches("[name=chooseDiv]")) return; // not a radio
    divs.forEach(div => div.hidden = div.id !== tgt.dataset.div)
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="orderhtml">
  <!--Header-->
  <header>
    <h1 class="header" id="headerTop">Sweet Life</h1>
    <h2 class="header" id="headerBottom">Discover a world of ice cream...</h2>
  </header>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <div id="topnav">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="order.html">Order online</a>
      <a href="register.html">Register</a>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="tagline">
    <h2>Order</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Form-->
  <form>
    <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
    <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
    <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="chooseDiv" value="Delivery" data-div="deliveryDiv"><br>
    <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
    <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="chooseDiv" value="Pickup" data-div="pickupDiv"><br>
  </form>

  <div id="pickupDiv" hidden>
    <br/>
    <p>A's text</p>
    <form id="orderPickupForm">
      <label for="fName">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" value=""><br>
      <label for="lName">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" value="">
      <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
      <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value=""><br>
      <select name="selectIceCream" id="selectIceCream">
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
      </select><br>
      <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
      <select name="selectSize" id="selectSize">
        <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
        <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
        <option value="1L">1L</option>
        <option value="2L">2L</option>
      </select><br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="deliveryDiv" hidden>
    <br/>
    <p>B's text</p>
    <form id="orderDeliveryForm">
      <label for="firstN">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="firstN" name="firstN" value=""><br>
      <label for="lastN">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lastN" name="lastN" value="">
      <label for="emailA">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="emailA" name="emailA" value=""><br>
      <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
      <select name="selectIceCream">
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
      </select><br>
      <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
      <select name="selectSize">
        <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
        <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
        <option value="1L">1L</option>
        <option value="2L">2L</option>
      </select><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your first solution by adding that code as a function and calling it in init. Nothing seems t have chenged, but now it doesn't work at all. Thank you though!

Comment: My code is complete replacement for your code. Do NOT call it in init! Delete init and the rest of the code you posted in your question. The DOMContentLoaded IS the init